# AngularJS and Codeigniter - Combination & Data Transfer

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I've recently started learning AngularJS and I was thinking about creating an application using codeigniter as the backend (as an API to insert, update and delete data to a MySQL database) and AngularJS as the frontend framework.
So my questions are: How would I accomplish this? I would I transfer the data between the two?

I wanna know a few details about it with examples because I can't find a good video tutorial where they combine the two. (found some tutorial about laravel & angular, Ruby on rails and angular but not really into those yet).
If someone knows a good video tutorial or even a blog post explaining this, please provide a link.

Found a few combo projects on GitHub but without any explanation what and how it is done, they are not really useful.

The only thing I know about this is that I have to return the data as json but I am not sure how to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: they run in completely different environments, angular doesn't care what back end is used. Transfer is same regardless of server api language or framework

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Combination of **CodeIgniter** and **AngularJS** would help you to build new range of **HTML5 Applications**.

Unlike JQuery, AngularJS is a front-end framework, which depends on the data from backend, all communications from the front-end happen through a **Controller Methods**, there are operations for *get* and *post* in Angular.

CodeIgniter will act as an **API** which will output an *json* response to the Angular controller.

I believe `json_encode(data)` will output the required **JSON** string, which upon receipt by front-end, the *data presentation* layer of Angular takes care of the things /or if you'd like to perform any operation over the data, Angular can do that also.

I don't hold any links for this combination, because most people have shifted towards **Ruby on Rails** and **AngularJS** combination, fearing the stop of new release of **CodeIgniter**

Regret for not having any satisfactory links/blog post.
If time allows me to make a *proof of concept*, I would be very happy to post the link.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

JSON

```
    [
        {"title": "t1"},
        {"title": "t2"}
        ....
     ]
```

HTML

```
 <body ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="MsgCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="m in msg">{{m.title}}</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </body>
```

JS

```
 var app = angular.module("app", []);

 app.controller("MsgCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/index.php/ctrlname/methodname').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     $scope.msg = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     // log error
    });
 });
```

---

**UPDATE**

For Insert, Delete, Update using **CodeIgniter** and **AngularJS**

CodeIgniter *Controller*

```
class Msg extends CI_Controller {

    public function retrieveall() { .. } // Retrieves all Content from the DB
    public function create(){ .. } // Inserts the given data to DB
    public function retrieve($id){ .. } // Retrieves specific data from the DB
    public function update($id, $title){ .. } // Updates specific data from the DB
    public function delete($id){ .. } // Deletes specific data from the DB

    ...

}
```

CodeIgniter *Routing*

```
$route['m'] = "msg";
$route['m/(:any)'] = "msg/$1";
```

*HTML*

```
<body ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="MsgCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="m in msg">
           {{m.title}}

           <a href="#" ng-click="delete(m.id)">Delete</a>
           <a href="#" ng-click="edit(m.id)">Edit</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <input type="text ng-model="create.title">
    <button type="submit" ng-click="formsubmit"> Submit </button>

     <input type="text ng-model="editc.title">
    <button type="submit" ng-click="editsubmit(editc.id)"> Submit </button>
   </div>
 </body>
```

*JS*

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

 app.controller("MsgCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/index.php/m/retrieveall').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     $scope.msg = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     // log error
    });

    $scope.delete = function($id) {
        $http.get('/index.php/m/delete/' + $id).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config)       {
        $scope.result = data;
    }

    $scope.edit = function($id) {
        $http.get('/index.php/m/retrieve/' + $id).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config)       {
        $scope.editc = data;
    }

    $scope.editsubmit = function($id) {
       $http.get('/index.php/m/update/' + $id +'/' + $scope.editc.title).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config)      {
        $scope.result = data;
    }
    }

    $scope.formsubmit = function($id) {
               $http.post('/index.php/m/create', {data: create}).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config)      {
                $scope.result = data;
         }
     }
 });
```

I believe this would help you understand. It's a bare example

Comment: the part about `Ruby on Rails` is garbage, back end is irrelevant. Likely more people using `node.js` with angular than Ruby

Comment: Ok so in the CI controller I'll return an array where it will have a status and message like $return = array ('status' = 'success', message = 'Yay! the insert was successful'); (same for the fail message) return json_encode($return); and how will I reach that from the angular side?

Comment: Ok cool, so if I wanna return any other data and not success and fail messages, should I do the same thing as my example but instead do $this->db>get(tablename); and return it as a json_encode()?

Comment: @Ruffles, I am sorry if I am misaligning your thought process, you can actually modify `json_encode()` to support the messages also, say response could be `{"message": "success", "content": [ {"title": "t1", ... ]}` and on the Angular side  *success* `if(data.message === "success") { $scope.msg = data.content }`.

Comment: Ok so how will routing work? Should I just leave the redirect part in the CI Controller when the function is called? Is there anything different that I should do?

Comment: Also can you give me an example of how to do insert, update and delete?

Comment: For Routing, if your going to have a single project with CodeIgniter + Angular then you can't give wildcard routing, check against the routes in Angular and redirect specific routes to **index.html**. Secondly if CodeIgniter API is different project and hosted anywhere else, and AngularJS is just a HTML Development you can specify in server config to all URI should access only the **index.html** (Apache - .htaccess, Nginx - default.conf)